# Group By and Count keywords for each log message using log insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a log message for eg:

```
Final list: "locale:locale1, locale=locale2, locale=locale1, locale=locale3"
```

How do I create a CloudWatch log insights query to count and group the locales count for each log message:

I want this output:

```
# locales_count value
1 2             locale1
1 1             locale2
1 1             locale3
```

or maybe just count the number of "locale=", eg:

```
# locales_count
1 4
```